# How to use MKBANNER in Automic UC4 job scheduler

Tags: scheduler

Here are the instructions:

1. Begin in the main screen of Applications Manager by clicking the green arrow/play button on the top menu.  This displays the Requests screen.
2. In the Requests screen search box enter mkbanner then click the Request button.  This displays the Submit screen.
3. In the Submit screen click the Select button for a list of available jobs.
4. Next screen has two columns or list boxes.  Scroll through the Unassigned list or enter the Banner job name in the search box. Highlight the job in the Unassigned list to select and click the blue right arrow button to move the job to the Assigned list box.  Click OK.
5. You return to the Submit screen.  It's not obvious that you have selected anything because your job name doesn't appear anywhere.  It just displays a "Ref= number" in the Prompts box.  Just click the Submit button now and you will hopefully see a message, "Job was Successfully submitted: Run ID = 99999".  Click the Close button.
6. Now you should be back in the main screen of Applications Manager.  After waiting a while, select the Jobs icon on the top menu. In the search box enter the name of the job you made.  It is displayed in the list.

Comment: These instructions are for version 8

Answer (score 0):

The answer is posted in the above instructions